# Unable to do Load Runner Scripting for .Net Desktop application

Tags: automated-testing, load-testing, performance-testing, loadrunner

I need to test a .Net windows application using LoadRunner *12.53*.

Tried couple of methods but no success.

- Method1:

  - Used .Net protocol and clicked start recording
  - `Error: Start Recording Failed. No recording log was created. LR failed to launch the desktop application.`
- Method2:

  - Used Web Http/Html protocol.
  - `Due to the below error, application cannot start 'Error:The Type initializer for (app.client.fromMainWrapper) threw an exception.`

Please suggest me what to do.

Comment: I would start from upgrading to a newer more supported version of LoadRunner

Comment: I'm allowed to use only 12.53. In general atleast the application should be invoked by Loadrunner. In my case it isn't.